# Application of Rao blackwell on possion distribuion

Tags: probability-theory

I have been finding it challenging doing the last problem. How do I make sure the $x_i's$ are independent when calculating it. part (i & ii) are pretty cool for me cos the coefficients of the $x_i's$ are all 1.

In part (iii), do I first have to find $ p(x_1+x_2+x_3|T) $ the find $ E(x_1+2x_2+3x_3|T) $? I just need a hint to proceed .

If $ x_i,  i=1, 2, 3, ...n$ are iid poisson random variable with mean $\lambda$, show that $T = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i $ is a complete statistics and find
 (i) $E(x_1 | T) $ 
(ii)$E(x_1+x_2|T) $
(iii)$ E(x_1+2x_2+3x_3|T) $

Comment: Use the linearity of conditional expectation: $$E(X_1 + 2X_2 + 3X_3 \mid T) = E(X_1 \mid T) + 2E(X_2 \mid T) + 3E(X_3 \mid T).$$ So if you are able to solve (i), (iii) doesn't have any new difficulty.

Comment: @ Solitary, I do understand the rule that you are using but don't forget $x_i$ are independent so we get $6 E(x|T)$ which i think is not right in relation to the question asked.